# Target _blank in all Link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, target

I've just made an html page with target `_self`

But now I have too many links and I want to change all link targets to `_blank` and it's hard for me to do. Is there is any javascript which apply on all just to write 1 time ??

Because my code is too long and it is taking too many times to change in all links. Is there is any trick?

like this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com"></a>
<a href="http://www.gmail.com"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com"></a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></a>
<a href="http://plus.google.com"></a>
```

Comment: What program are you using to write your html? The obvious way would be a find and replace...

Comment: No problem for stupid question. I would handle this situation with a better editor, like Sublime Text.
In Sublime Text, you would do:
1. Search for "href"
2. Click on "Find all", which selects all "href" results.
3. write your "target" before the "href"

Comment: noo i dont want to replace is there is any javascipt which open all links in blank?

Comment: Btw the link URLs in your example are incorrect...they should start with http://

Comment: but i want to edit in inspect element

Comment: @PeeHaa Tell me pllsss

Comment: I'm confident the answer is in here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+open+links+in+tab

Comment: You shouldn't try to use javascript as a find-and-replace substitute.

Comment: @ThomWiggers's comment is definitely true. I'm hoping that there's some good reason that the links need to not actually have a `target` attribute in the HTML, otherwise you really should change your HTML.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Put this in your `<head>`:

```html
<base target="_blank">
```

It will make all URLs on a page open in a new page, *unless* `target` is specified.

This is a HTML5-only feature, I learned it from [Google's io-2012-slides slide package](https://code.google.com/p/io-2012-slides/).

Comment: I don't know, why don't you try? It will not update the rendered HTML code, however...

Comment: Are you using HTML5? Also it might not get executed since `<head>` was already executed at page load. Just put the code into your page's `<head>` and you shouldn't have to change the `target` on URLs anymore.

Comment: FYI the default behavior is `target="_self"`

Answer (score 8):

To answer your question, jQuery makes this easy:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a[href]').attr('target', '_blank');
    });
</script>
```

This will not modify any `<a>` tags without an `href` attribute.

Comment: @Hammad It should work... try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/Hh4S6/ You probably don't have jQuery loaded or your not waiting for your document to load before changing the `target` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple in plain JS too:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0, len=links.length; i < len; i++) {
  links[i].target = '_blank';
}
```

(Put this script right before your closing `</body>` tag or in any case after all the `<a>` tags on your page.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to do a simple `find and replace` using your HTML editor,  you can do something like this using jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

This will automatically do a `target="_blank"` for every `a` that is clicked and open in a new window or new tab(you have no control over this,  it depends on user's browser settings).

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ef7R/)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Its important to add jquery 2.1.0 ?

Comment: Probably because you didn't put the script at the bottom of your page (before the closing `</body>` tag) or alternatively inside a `$(document).ready()` callback.

Comment: Note that the jQuery 2.x branch does not support IE 8 and below.

Comment: Also note that unlike the other answers here, this answer doesn't change the target until someone actually clicks on a link, so it should appear before any of your other JS code that might set up `click` events on links (unless none of those other JS links [if you have any] need to actually open in a new window/tab).

Comment: @Hammad Not necessary,  any recent version of jQuery should work.  But having a jQuery include is required.  Though,  2.X may not work below IE8,  it's good for other browsers. The code is jQuery code which you need to put in a `$(document).ready(function(){ //...code here..});` inside `script` tags.

Answer (score 1):

I've had to deal with this *lots* of times. Just for the record:

I think there's no need to make javascript perform this task, but here's another approach, instead you can use the find/replace function of your editor and do something like this (provided your links are in that format):

- Open your editor and look for `<a href`:

  [image: Find <a href]
- On the replace field type `<a`*`target="_blank"`*`href`.

  [image: Replace]
- Replace.

  [image: Text replaced]

Or you can append that to the end of the tag by looking for `.com">` and replacing it for `.com" target="_blank">`. You can do this on *all editors* that have the *find/replace* feature. It's just a matter of finding patterns and how to replace them.