# How to add target=_blank automatically to PDF links using PHP?

Tags: wordpress

I'm wondering is it possible to automatically add `target=_blank` to any PDF link I have on my website, so that it will convert

```
<a href="pdf1.pdf">link text</a>
<a href="pdf2.pdf">link text</a>
```

to

```
<a href="Pdf1.pdf" target="_blank">link text</a>
<a href="Pdf2.pdf" target="_blank">link text</a>
```

as this site has a lot of PDFs, and it would be easier to do this automatically rather than have to set them all one-by-one.

I have tried the Javascript solution:

```
$(".newWindow a[href$='pdf']").attr('target','_blank');
```

But am wondering is there a way to do this automatically in PHP, perhaps by adding something to Wordpress's functions file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428476/target-blank-in-all-link/24560618#24560618

Comment: All those provide Javascript solutions, which is not the solution I have asked for.

Comment: Not all of them, you can notice that if you actually read through the page.

Comment: The Find/Replace one would be useful if all the PDFs were being added at once, but they will be added intermittently. While the <base target="_blank"> solution won't work as the page contains links that are non PDF links.

Comment: It is actually the part of the search patterns that matters, you can implement that approach using any tool you want, like in Valentin Mercier's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.pdf` links are ***only*** in your pages content. The fastest and easiest way to to do it is to replace inside your theme template file that shows your page content the following:

```
the_content();
```

by

```
echo str_replace('.pdf"', '.pdf" target="_blank"', get_the_content());
```

This will be inside the file `content.php`of your theme.

**Note that** the function quoted above may have a parameter, (for example `the_content('',FALSE,'');`) you need to pass the same parameter in the `get_the_content()`function as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, you can perform smarter replacements. This example below will work on all `<a>` tags with a PDF extension in the URL, even if the URL has parameters.

```
echo preg_replace('/((<a (?=.*\.pdf)(?!.*target="_blank").*?)>)/', '$2 target="_blank">', get_the_content());
```

This regex performs two lookaheads: first, to check if the URL contains a PDF extension; and second, to check if the `target="_blank"` attribute is not already set. If both of those requirements are satisfied, then it will append the `target="_blank"` attribute to the end of the tag.