# Make a link from Electron open in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is there any (simple/built-in way) to open a new browser (I mean default OS browser) window for a link from Electron instead of visiting that link inside your Electron app ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I force external links from browser-window to open in a default browser from Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402327/how-can-i-force-external-links-from-browser-window-to-open-in-a-default-browser)

Comment: One of this one or the [linked one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402327/how-can-i-force-external-links-from-browser-window-to-open-in-a-default-browser) from @m4tt1mus  should be closed. They are exactly the same question. This was asked earlier - but I don't know what is the defining criteria.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can simply use :

```
require("shell").openExternal("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Better answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402327/how-can-i-force-external-links-from-browser-window-to-open-in-a-default-browser

Comment: is it ok to open a site inside electron?and navigate back and forward

Comment: @John It wouldn't be a big deal, but I'd take hints from other Electron apps and see how they handle links. Discord and Slack open links in the browser (non-mobile), and I think that's a good precedent.

Comment: How to open an external link through electron app but with a specific choosed browser, for example chrome? I dont want to change my settings and I dont want to open with explorer ( my default browser)... @zianwar #help someone ?

Comment: What if I want to open an external website across all the browser? For ex: Chrome, Mozilla, and Edge?

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how or where you should use this. [@Evgenii's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67108615/327074) should be the accepted one.

Comment: This answer doesn't make it clear where to add this. It sounds like every time you need to open a link, you should call this line, but what we need is a configuration that makes it a default behaviour, which is what Greg pointed out in the first comment. that one is indeed the best answer to this question

Answer (score 37):

EDIT: [@Evgenii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67108615/327074) is much better these days.

This answer is quite old and assumes you have jQuery.

```
const shell = require('electron').shell;
  
// assuming $ is jQuery
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    shell.openExternal(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 26):

### Update

`on('new-window'..` is deprecated since electron 22. use `setWindowOpenHandler` instead.

```js
webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
  return { action: 'deny' }
})
```

Check other answers.
deprecation info: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-webcontents-new-window-event

### old Answer (pre electron 22)

```js
mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function(e, url) {
  e.preventDefault();
  require('electron').shell.openExternal(url);
});
```

Requires that you use target="_blank" on your anchor tags.

Comment: Any method to handle links without target="_blank"? Maybe one way is to add `<base target="_blank">` to head https://stackoverflow.com/a/24428525/2129219

Comment: "new-window" is deprecated since electron 22. use this answer instead: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67108615/4394435

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-webcontents-new-window-event

Answer (score 19):

My code snippet clue accordingly to the depreciations in Electron version ^12.0.0, put this code in your 'entry point' `main.js` (or whatever you call it):

```
const win = new BrowserWindow();
win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
    // config.fileProtocol is my custom file protocol
    if (url.startsWith(config.fileProtocol)) {
        return { action: 'allow' };
    }
    // open url in a browser and prevent default
    shell.openExternal(url);
    return { action: 'deny' };
});
```

Links must also have `target="_blank"`.

Comment: In case someone wants to know the "deny" and "allow" rules. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now - it has a mirror answer in the similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409223/327074.

Answer (score 5):

Some handy solutions can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/luizcarraro/2d04d83e66e3f03bef9b2e714ea8c0d7).

By listening on the body, the following solutions will work on `<a>` tags that **may not yet exist** when the JavaScript runs, but only appear in the DOM at a later time.

This one by [luizcarraro](https://github.com/luizcarraro) requires jQuery:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  require("electron").shell.openExternal(event.target.href);
});
```

You can change the selector to target only certain links, e.g. `'#messages-view a'` or `'a.open-external'`.

Here is an alternative without any library (derived from [zrbecker](https://github.com/zrbecker)'s):

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    event.preventDefault();
    require("electron").shell.openExternal(event.target.href);
  }
});
```

Consult [the gist](https://gist.github.com/luizcarraro/2d04d83e66e3f03bef9b2e714ea8c0d7) for more examples.

Comment: I used the following test: `if (event.target.href && event.target.href.match(/^https?:\/\//))`.

Answer (score 4):

To make all Electron links to open externally in the default OS browser you will have to add an `onclick` property to them and change the `href` property so it doesn't load anything in the Electron app.

You could use something like this:

```js
aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
  aTags[i].setAttribute("onclick","require('shell').openExternal('" + aTags[i].href + "')");
  aTags[i].href = "#";
}
```

But **make sure the entire document has loaded *before* doing** this otherwise it is not going to work.
A more robust implementation would look like this:

```js
if (document.readyState != "complete") {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    prepareTags()
  }, false);
} else {
  prepareTags();
}

function prepareTags(){
  aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    aTags[i].setAttribute("onclick","require('shell').openExternal('" + aTags[i].href + "')");
    aTags[i].href = "#";
  }
  return false;
}
```

Remember that if you load external files you will have to make them go through this process as well **after** they are fully loaded.

Comment: You should learn about event delegation, which only requires one event listener, can handle newly created elements without extra code, and is more efficient. You shouldn't use the `onclick` attribute to define an event listener; you should use `addEventListener` instead. You've introduced a security vulnerability, which can be demonstrated with `<a href="'+alert('exploit!')+'">exploit</a>`. (Finally, there are also alternative solutions to this problem that don't involve the DOM at all)

Comment: @1j01 You managed to be rude and condescending without actually providing a better answer. This is a forum, if you have a more reliable solution, please answer the OP so others can also benefit from the knowledge.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude; I meant what I said in earnest. I was trying to fit within the comment length limit which distracted me from how to best present what I was trying to say in polite way (that comes across as polite). Maybe I should have split it into multiple comments... Also I should use less "you" statements, for sure.

Comment: **Rephrased:** A better way to listen for click events for all links would be [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), which only requires one listener, and works with newly created elements without special handling. Also, you shouldn't use the `onclick` attribute. The concatenation of code together with data here introduces a security vulnerability where a third party could potentially execute arbitrary code. [Here's a demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/1j01/6evh0n8r/)

Comment: **Rephrasing continued:** [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) is preferred over `onclick` because it allows multiple event listeners to be added to the same element, but you could also use [`element.onclick = function(){ ... }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) if you don't need to worry about listeners being overwritten.

Comment: Also if you *do* ever need to embed data in JS code, you could use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (which works on strings as well as objects), e.g. `"require('shell').openExternal(" + JSON.stringify(aTags[i].href) + ")"`

Answer (score 4):

I use this method with Electron v.13.

We intercept the user's navigation (`window.location`) and open the URL in the default browser.

See the doc : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-will-navigate

```
const { shell } = require('electron');

window.webContents.on('will-navigate', function (e, url) {
    e.preventDefault();
    shell.openExternal(url);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 4):

In the view component use simple `a` link:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
  <button type="button">
    button title
  </button>
</a>
```

And in file `public/electron.js` add default behavior for all `a` link navigations:

```
function createWindow() {
  ...
  // Open urls in the user's browser
  win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((edata) => {
    shell.openExternal(edata.url);
    return { action: "deny" };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On `tsx` syntax (**Electron**):

```
import { shell } from "electron";
shell.openExternal("http://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2023

Since electron 22 `on('new-window')` is deprecated. You need to use `setWindowOpenHandler` and add a target="_black" to your links

```
  mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
    require("electron").shell.openExternal(details.url);
    return { action: 'deny' }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

To open an external link in an Electron's Project you will need the module Shell (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shell) and the method `openExternal`.

But if you are looking for an abstract way to implement that logic is by creating a handler for a custom target to your target attribute.

```
const {shell} = require('electron');

if (document.readyState != "complete") {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        init()
    }, false);
} else {
    init();
}

function init(){
    handleExternalLinks();
    //other inits
}


function handleExternalLinks(){
    let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
    let a,i = 0;
    while (links[i]){
        a = links[i]
        //If <a target="_external">, so open using shell.
        if(a.getAttribute('target') == '_external'){
            a.addEventListener('click',(ev => {
                ev.preventDefault();
                let url = a.href;
                shell.openExternal(url);
                a.setAttribute('href', '#');
                return false;
            }))
        }
        console.log(a,a.getAttribute('external'))
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to set watcher for openExternal(URL); I want to set watcher for opened page's specific URL and when I got that URL Need to close the browser window or tab?

Comment: @NikunjBeladiya in this case you should set manually the attribute target="_external" for each link that you want to open in a new window. Or make a kind of switch in the identifier of your page.

Answer (score 0):

To run an Electron project in your actual browser (Chrome, Mozilla, etc), add this to your script are external script:

```
aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
     aTags[i].setAttribute("onclick","require('shell').openExternal('" + aTags[i].href + "')");
     aTags[i].href = "#";
}
```

Comment: You don't need more than one event listener (you can use event delegation which will handle newly created elements and be more efficient, and there are alternative solutions to this problem that don't involve the DOM at all). You shouldn't use the `onclick` attribute to define an event listener. You've introduced a security vulnerability, e.g. `<a href="'+alert('exploit!')+'">exploit</a>` - you should use `addEventListener` instead. (or at least e.g. `aTags[i].onclick = ()=> { require('shell').openExternal(this.href) }` which is very short, but destroys any existing listener added in this way)