# How can I force external links from browser-window to open in a default browser from Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm using the [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) to display an app and I would like to force the external links to be opened in the default browser. Is that even possible or I have to approach this differently?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Update: this does not work in electron >= 22 because `on('new-window'` has been removed.

I came up with this, after checking the solution from the previous answer.

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function(e, url) {
  e.preventDefault();
  require('electron').shell.openExternal(url);
});
```

According to the [electron spec](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-new-window), `new-window` is fired when external links are clicked.

*NOTE: Requires that you use `target="_blank"` on your anchor tags.*

Comment: doesn't `new-window` only fire when `target` is set to `_blank`?

Comment: @YanFoto maybe my bad.. but by external I meant that.. I tried the `will-navigate` but it didn't work in my case..

Comment: @lipis now i get it! I thought you meant everything which is not local :D

Comment: Don't know what ```shell``` should be but I used the npm node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/open to open the external link. So my code looks exactly the same instead of line ```require('shell').openExternal(url);``` that is ```var open = require('open'); open(url);```

Comment: Instead of `require('shell')`, which threw an error for me, I was able to get this to work using `electron.shell.openExternal(url);`

Comment: `main` is the window returned when you create your browser window with `new BrowserWindow()`

Comment: @Doug `shell` is a part of `electron`, not a separate module. So you need to use `require( "electron" ).shell` or `const { shell } = require( "electron" )`

Comment: `new-window` is deprecated in Electron 12. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409223/1394731

Answer (score 78):

`new-window` is now deprecated in favor of `setWindowOpenHandler` in Electron 12 (see https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/24517).

So a more up to date answer would be as follows, this goes in your 'entry point' file for example `main.js`:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()

mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
  shell.openExternal(url);
  return { action: 'deny' };
});
```

See also the electron docs [Native `window` example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/window-open#native-window-example).

This will affect *all* links in your electron app that have `target="_blank"` set.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me some time to configure it myself while checking the official electron documentation:

new-window -> `Deprecated in favor of webContents.setWindowOpenHandler.`

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-new-window-deprecated

Comment: Ensure that you are importing `shell` from electron:
const { shell } = require('electron')

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#how-12

Comment: If I write an url like `www.foo.com` , it will open `localhost:3000/www.foo.com`. How to only open the link without the localhost prefix?

Comment: @DoneDeal0 You need to add the "https://" to make it a URL.

Comment: oo yeah, just made a fool out of myself lol, thanks!

Comment: if you are on es6, import shell with `import { shell } from 'electron'`

Comment: @chiayongkang good point - although VS Code sorted this out for me

Answer (score 10):

Improved from the accepted answer ;

1. the link must be `target="_blank"` ;
2. add in `background.js`(or anywhere you created your window) :

   ```
   window.webContents.on('new-window', function(e, url) {
     // make sure local urls stay in electron perimeter
     if('file://' === url.substr(0, 'file://'.length)) {
       return;
     }

     // and open every other protocols on the browser      
     e.preventDefault();
     shell.openExternal(url);
   });
   ```

**Note :** To ensure this behavior across all application windows, this code should be run after each window creation.

Comment: Good point on the `target` - electron calls the 'entry point' where you create your window `main.js` - see their [Quick Start scaffolding](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start#scaffold-the-project) docs

Comment: Also of course `webContents.on('new-window'...` is deprecated now

Answer (score 8):

If you're not using `target="_blank"` in your `anchor` elements, this might work for you:

```
  const shell = require('electron').shell;

  $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    shell.openExternal(this.href);
  });
```

Comment: This assumes JQuery I imagine?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter yes

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this but I assume this is should work:

1) Get [`WebContents`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md) of the your `BrowserWindow`

```
 var wc = browserWindow.webContents;
```

2) Register for [`will-navigate`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-will-navigate) of `WebContent` and intercept navigation/link clicks:

```js
wc.on('will-navigate', function(e, url) {
  /* If url isn't the actual page */
  if(url != wc.getURL()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    openBrowser(url);
  } 
}
```

3) Implement `openBrowser` using [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). An example for Linux desktops:

```js
var openBrowser(url) {
  require('child_process').exec('xdg-open ' + url);
}
```

let me know if this works for you!

Comment: @SkyzohKey you edited the condition from pseudo code that said "If url is external"; did you actually test that `url != wc.getURL()` is helpful? I imagine it would always be true.

Answer (score 4):

For anybody coming by.

My use case:

I was using [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor) in my app and it's preview mode was opening links in the same window. I wanted all links to open in the default OS browser. I put this snippet, based on the other answers, inside my main.js file.  It calls it after it creates the new BrowserWindow instance.  My instance is called mainWindow

```
let wc = mainWindow.webContents
wc.on('will-navigate', function (e, url) {
  if (url != wc.getURL()) {
    e.preventDefault()
    electron.shell.openExternal(url)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the requested url is an external link. If yes then use `shell.openExternal`.

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function(e, reqUrl) {
  let getHost = url=>require('url').parse(url).host;
  let reqHost = getHost(reqUrl);
  let isExternal = reqHost && reqHost != getHost(wc.getURL());
  if(isExternal) {
    e.preventDefault();
    electron.shell.openExternal(reqUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: As of newer versions of electron, this freezes your app.

Comment: @vsecades Which version do you mean? There is no issue as my test on electron electron v26.0.0 and v19.1.9

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `renderer side js` file.  It'll open `http`, `https` links in user's default browser.

No JQuery attached! no `target="_blank"` required!

```
let shell = require('electron').shell
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'A' && event.target.href.startsWith('http')) {
    event.preventDefault()
    shell.openExternal(event.target.href)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For Electron 5, this is what worked for me:

- In `main.js` (where you create your browser window), include 'shell' in your main require statement (usually at the top of the file), e.g.:

  ```
  // Modules to control application life and create native browser window
  const {
      BrowserWindow,
      shell
  } = require('electron');
  ```
- Inside the `createWindow()` function, after `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ ... })`, add these lines:

  ```
  mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', function(e, url) {
      e.preventDefault();
      shell.openExternal(url);
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by the following step

1. Add shell on `const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')`

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, shell} = require('electron')
```

2. Set nativeWindowOpen is true

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1350,
    height: 880,
    webPreferences: {
      nativeWindowOpen: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    },
    icon: path.join(__dirname, './img/icon.icns')
})
```

3. Add the following listener code

```
  mainWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function(e, reqUrl) {
    let getHost = url=>require('url').parse(url).host;
    let reqHost = getHost(reqUrl);
    let isExternal = reqHost && reqHost !== getHost(wc.getURL());
    if(isExternal) {
      e.preventDefault();
      shell.openExternal(reqUrl, {});
    }
  })
```

reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/42570770/7458156 by cuixiping

Comment: Hi, please where should the listener code be placed ? Inside the html, main.js or preload.js ?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use these lines in external `.js` script:

```
let ele = document.createElement("a");
let url = "https://google.com";
ele.setAttribute("href", url);
ele.setAttribute("onclick", "require('electron').shell.openExternal('" + url + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new window using `window.open()` then use the `setWindowOpenHandler` as `new-window` is depreciated.

I was working on react and had to open my component in new window. Also, this window does not have a url I used the `frameName` property to open the browserWindow in electron. However you may use `url` also inside if condition block.

```js
window.open("", "CallWindow", features);
```

```js
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ frameName }) => {
   // Dynamically give position to opened window
    const leftPos = screen.getPrimaryDisplay().size.width - 420;
    const topPos = 60;

    if (frameName === "CallWindow") {
      return {
        action: "allow",
        overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
          width: 360,
          height: 728,
          minWidth: 220,
          minHeight: 220,
          x: leftPos,
          y: topPos,
          autoHideMenuBar: true,
        },
      };
    }
    return { action: "deny" };
  });
```

Following link shows how to use `setWindowOpenHandler`.
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/window-open.md