# Opening external links in Electron with the HTML anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm making an electron app and I want to make a button in my `index.html` file to open up the default internet browser (ex. Chrome) to my GitHub repository website. I have seen other StackOverflow questions on this with successful answers, but they contain snippets of JavaScript and I don't know where to put them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I force external links from browser-window to open in a default browser from Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402327/how-can-i-force-external-links-from-browser-window-to-open-in-a-default-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [shell module](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/shell.md#shellopenexternalurl):

Add the following code to your main.js:

At its beginning:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');
const {shell} = require('electron');
```

After the app.on function:

```
ipcMain.on('loadGH', (event, arg) => {
    shell.openExternal(arg);
});
```

Within the head of your index.html you then need to instantiate the ICP module:

```
<script>
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
</script>
```

Then use the onclick event  to actually perform the loading of the new window:

```
<a HREF="#" onclick="ipc.send('loadGH','http://github.com/yourGitHubName');">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I forgot to add that in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

**This answer references an earlier ambigious version of the question, then hinting at the need to open a new electron window.**

When you say "external link" I assume you want to open another window containing your github repo.

This can be done by adding the following code to your *main.js*:

At its beginning:

```
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;
```

Inside the *app.on* function:

```
var externalWindow = new BrowserWindow ({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
})
```

After the *app.on* function:

```
ipcMain.on('loadGH', (event, arg) => {
    externalWindow.loadURL(arg);
});
```

Within the head of your index.html you then need to instantiate the ICP module:

```
<script>
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
</script>
```

Then use the onclick event in an href to actually perform the loading of the new window:

```
<a HREF="#" onclick="ipc.send('loadGH','http://github.com/yourGitHubName');">Link</a>
```

Comment: Which `app.on` function should the first and second snippets go in? I have two `app.on` functions and the first one checks if the application if the `process.platform` is not equal to `darwin`. In the comments made by the GitHub, it says it has something to do with OS X. I'm not sure if you have these extra functions or not--our `main.js` files may be different. The one I just mentioned is also declared like so... `app.on('window-all-closed', function() {`

Comment: That's fine, you'll have to look for app.on('ready', function {... }), this is the one that is called upon app start.

Comment: whoops... it appears I didn't ask my question right. I actually wanted to open up the default internet browser containing my GitHub repo. I'll fix that above.