# electronjs open links in default browser?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Hello guys I am currently making a desktop app and in electronjs I have a feedback link and I want that when I click on the link that I get in my browser and not in a new window or something because I have the app window in 820x550 and if the page opens in the app it looks not good so I would love if someone could help... my main.js

```
// main.js

// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const { shell } = require('electron')


function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 820,
    height: 550,
    resizable: false
  })
  

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
  mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)


  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Einige APIs können nur nach dem Auftreten dieses Events genutzt werden.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. Sie können den Code auch 
// auf mehrere Dateien aufteilen und diese hier einbinden.
//console.time('Starting time');

//console.time('Require time 1');
/*
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {

  alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
  return true;

}*/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I force external links from browser-window to open in a default browser from Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402327/how-can-i-force-external-links-from-browser-window-to-open-in-a-default-browser)

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner yes I saw this before but I I couldn't read for a sec >.< thx 谢谢

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to provide a link that opens a url, you can simply get the shell from electron module and call one of its methods inside an event handler as follows:

```
const { shell } = require('electron');

shell.openExternal('<your url>');
```