# Is it possible to pack a react app into a distributable and install on any computer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, exe, monorepo, pack

I have a web application with React front end and Node backend. I want to pack this whole app into a distributable (exe msi etc) and install on clients machine. Once they start the app it will run the server on a local port and react app will run in the browser on another local port. Is this possible? If so what tools should I use?

Comment: Proton, Electron, NodeGui... to name a few search for:  "React cross platform native desktop app"

Comment: It looks like these tools are to turn a web application to a desktop app. What I want is to still open the apps on an actual browser. i

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402327/how-can-i-force-external-links-from-browser-window-to-open-in-a-default-browser