# Open iframe link in the browser using electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, electron

I want to open an iframe link in a browser using electron. I found some solutions but they are not working, here are examples I tried:

- [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-open-link-in-browser)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749625/make-a-link-from-electron-open-in-browser)

I think the problem is, that the link is in the scr Tag.

Looking for a possible solution why nothing is working

Here is an example iframe element

```
<iframe src="https://rcm-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?o=3&p=48&l=ur1&category=channels&banner=138WWDCBD6MQJVWGMHG2&f=ifr&linkID=0335593f7b48da8f8d1dab568039dc08&t=adrgoe-21&tracking_id=adrgoe-21" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And here is my Electron code

```
const shell = require('electron').shell;

// assuming $ is jQuery
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    shell.openExternal(this.href);
});
```

Comment: Please provide code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/XUdb7DdV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
I changed the iframe to a webview:

```
<webview id="webview" src="https://stackoverflow.com/" nodeintegration></webview>
```

The JS is now:

```
const {shell} = require('electron')
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')
webview.addEventListener('will-navigate', (e) => {
  const protocol = require('url').parse(e.url).protocol
  if (protocol === 'http:' || protocol === 'https:') {
    shell.openExternal(e.url)
  }
});
```

Instead of 'will-navigate' you can choose different actions. [Find the all here](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#dom-events)

```
webview.addEventListener('will-navigate', (e) => {
```

Now I have to find out, how to stop change the page in the webview.
But it open the link in the default browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are detecting clicks on `a[href^="http"]` but your tag is an `iframe`

Really you should give the iframe an `id` or something then handle your click targeting it. e.g.

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="...></iframe>
```

and

```
const shell = require('electron').shell;

// assuming $ is jQuery
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe')
    console.log(iframe, event.target) // what are these?
    if(iframe) {
       shell.openExternal(iframe.href);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to use the code and tried a few things on it. But I do not get it that the link in a standard browser is opened.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the [threads](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1378) on github one way to do this is to use a `<webview>` instead of an `<iframe>`. Then put code like this in your main.js/browser process *NOT* the renderer process

```
app.on('web-contents-created', (event, contents) => {
  if (contents.getType() === 'webview') {
    contents.on('will-navigate', (event, url) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      shell.openExternal(url);
    });
  }
});
```

Putting code in the renderer process won't work, at least as of Electron 1.8.4