# how can I create link which will be open in a browser not on app

Tags: hyperlink, electron, quasar-framework

How can I create link which will be open in a browser not on app (I creating a desktop app)

I'm using Quasar Framework with Electron Wrapper. Default method openUrl() open url in app (in new window) (same when using ). I need open it in User/OS-default web browser

Comment: What are you using for your desktop application? Can you provide more details? How about a sample code of what you've done so far?

Comment: I'm using Quasar Framework with Electron Wrapper. 
Default method openUrl() open url in app (in new window) (same when using <a href="...">).

I need open it in User/OS-default web browser

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. That's a bit better, you had the wrong tags. Now I know where to look :)  You can show `openUrl()` as a code sample to improve your answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749625/make-a-link-from-electron-open-in-browser helps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a link from Electron open in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749625/make-a-link-from-electron-open-in-browser)

Comment: thanks, we use this, but it won't work... but it is working on Electron w/o Quasar.
Thanks!

Comment: and @GeekyI it is not duplicated - because it is about Quasar, not Electron. :)