# How to open a link in default browser in an electron app

Tags: javascript, web, electron, electron-forge

I want to know how to open a web link in the default browser when clicked on a button in an electron app. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a link from Electron open in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749625/make-a-link-from-electron-open-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your main.js, make sure the following variables are defined:

```js
const ipc = ipcMain;
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, webContents } = require('electron');
```

Inside your button onclick function (in the renderer), use the following:

```js
ipc.send('SomeEvent');
```

Also make sure the following are defined in your renderer

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const ipc = ipcRenderer;
```

Then, use the following to open in the external browser (it will open in the user's default)

```js
ipc.on('SomeEvent', ()=>{
  require('electron').shell.openExternal('<LINK_HERE>');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this also not working

Comment: Can you provide an error log so I can see what's going on and where the error occurs?